# How can I download a file (fileme.us) in tor browser?

Tags: configuration, help

How can I download a file (fileme.us) in tor browser? Whenever I click "download" does not enter the offerings so that I can complete to perform the download. It is very important if anyone knows, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't depend by Tor Browser. If you try to download a file and the site ask you for an offer there is not so much to do, the fact that the site ask you for an offer has nothing to do with Tor Browser.